# Behaviour of Betti tables with exact sequences

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $0 \to M' \to M \to M'' \to 0$ be an exact sequence of finitely generated graded $S$-modules, where $S=k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ is a polynomial ring in $n$ variables.  Let $\beta_{i,j}(M)$ denote the graded Betti numbers of $M$, which are defined using a minimal free resolution of $M$.  Is it true that $$\beta_{i,j}(M)=\beta_{i,j}(M')+\beta_{i,j}(M''),$$ for all $i,j$?

Answer (score 2):

Generic counterexample: Let $I$ be a homogeneous ideal of $S$. Then we have a short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow S \rightarrow S/I \rightarrow 0$ of finitely generated graded $S$-modules. Since $S$ is free all of its Betti numbers are zero. But if $\beta_{i,j}(S) = \beta_{i,j}(I) + \beta_{i,j}(S/I)$ was true this would imply that all Betti numbers of $I$ and $S/I$ are zero (since Betti numbers are nonnegative), which can not be the case in general. This answers your question negatively.